# php mb_ereg() not working properly width Arabic

Tags: php, unicode, arabic

mb_ereg()  not working properly.

```
$badword ="ناك";  // which mean F***.

$TextToCheck = "في الكون هناك الكثير من الكواكب"; // In universe there's a lot of planets.

mb_ereg("\b".$badword."\b", $TextToCheck, $text);

echo $text[0]; // the output $text : ناك
```

which mean that the word ("هناك" = there) is found as "ناك" which mean that mb_ereg didn't get in count the first letter "ه" (هـ) "";

any way there's many other situation like this, any solution?

Comment: I think the problem is with your file encoding,

the function works fine with me,

for example: https://3v4l.org/lUKn8

Comment: You are the man, it's not really about encoding but about php version, I have php v5.3.0, when I change it to 5.6 on the server is worked just fine.

It's a more than 5 hours tests/searches and no luck, so Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_match` instead of `mb_ereg` function

```
$badword ="ناك";  // which mean ****.

$TextToCheck = "في الكون هناك الكثير من الكواكب"; // In universe there's a lot of planets.

preg_match("/".$badword."/", $TextToCheck, $text);

echo $text[0];
```

Comment: No this is not right cause the output in this case should be empty because there's no word = 'ناك', there's a different 'هناك'.

Comment: هناك contains the word   ناك  isnot it